# Move a ImageButton into the StatusBar

Tags: user-interface, maui

I have an Image button with a "+" as can be seen on the following Image.

How can I move this ImageButton into the Status Bar of my ContentPage as can be seen on the following ScreenShot?

When I have it within a Grid or other Layout and move it around it is just move within that, not outside

[image]

================== As requested here some Code =====================

***AppShell.xaml***

```xml
<TabBar x:Name="TabBar">
    <Tab Icon="home.png" Title="Home" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Home}" Route="Home" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Icon="Settings.png" Title="Settings" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Settings}" Route="Settings" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

***ContentPage.xaml***

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">

    <Frame Grid.Row="1" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="250" WidthRequest="365"
           IsClippedToBounds="True" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="20" Margin="15,-485,50,15" Padding="0"
           BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" Opacity="0.9">

        <StackLayout>
            
            <Label Text="Description what to do with the Labels:" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="15,15" />

            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" Padding="15,15">
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label1: "/>
                <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="e.g. label1"  Margin="0,-12,10,0"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label2: "/>
                <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="e.g. label2"   Margin="0,-12,10,0"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label3: "/>
                <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="e.g. label2"   Margin="0,-12,10,0" />
            </Grid>

            <Button Text="DoSomeStuff" WidthRequest="120" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>

        </StackLayout>

    </Frame>

    <Frame Grid.Row="2" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="440" WidthRequest="365"
           IsClippedToBounds="True" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="20" Margin="15,-220,50,15" Padding="0"
           BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" Opacity="0.85">

        <!-- Here I wanted to move the Round Button Image to the Bottom into the Shell TabBar 
             between Tab 'Home' and 'Settings' -->
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,50" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TranslationY="-15">
                <ImageButton Source="round_button.svg" HeightRequest="80"/>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>            

    </Frame>

</Grid>
```

Comment: That's not the status bar. The status bar is where it shows the time, battery level, and so on. You should show some code and explain the current situation better instead of just showing what you want to achieve. Do you already have a bottom navigation implemented? If you don't want to use MAUI's built-in Shell Tabs, you can also use [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) which supports a feature button in the bottom tab navigation.

Comment: Sorry, for using misleading terms. I was talking about the MAUI TabBar implemented in Shell. On the ContentPage I use a Grid. In this Grid, I have 2 Rows and the last Row has a ImageButton. This one I wanted to move with TranslationY="..." but this is not on top of the Grid. It is moved downwards the grid and disappears

Comment: Your button is not part of the TabBar, right? Please show the relevant code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: are you only targeting Windows?  If so MAUI might not be the best framework to use

Comment: @ewerspej - I provided the code above. Is there a way to move this ImageButton down into the TabBar of the Shell as kind of an Overlay. So, position it freely on Top of everything else that is displayed?

Comment: @Jason - It is ment for use on iOS and Android, but not on Windows

Comment: @OXO You cannot place elements of a Page on top of the TabBar, AFAIK. As mentioned before, you might want to check out Sharpnado.Tabs instead of using MAUI's TabBar. Otherwise, you'll have to implement all that by yourself as MAUI doesn't support such a centered feature button in the TabBar. Apart from at that Buttons in a bottom navigation bar (such as the TabBar) should also be always visible, independent of the page that is currently active, otherwise it will confuse your users.

Comment: Hhm, thought there could be some Layering tricks, e.g. working with ContentViews, ZIndexes or TranslationY/TranslationX to achieve such an effect  Unfortunately, too many restrictions then all over the place in .NET MAUI from what is state of the art in modern App UI development

Comment: It doesn't have to do with state-of-the-art anything. MAUI, just like Xamarin.Forms, uses native controls coupled with composed controls, which allows apps to look native to their respective platform while still sharing the same code base. What you want to do is possible, just not in the way you're asking. Your approach doesn't work, because of the view hierarchy. Yes, layering is possible using Grids, AbsoluteLayouts and also in some ways using z-Indices with those layouts. I would just use Sharpnado.Tabs instead of Shell's TabBar, if I was you.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to implement it on my own is less or no dependencies to other libraries. Well, on the Screenshots it looks good, so gave it a try. But, as soon as I added the NuGet package for it, I get lots of errors like „XamlC error XFC000: Cannot resolve type „RespurceDictionary“ and so the n. It doesn’t know my ContentPages anymore and so on  Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Comment: Which package did you install? It needs to be this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sharpnado.Tabs.Maui

Comment: @ewerspej - I took the one from Manage NuGet Packages Dialog. But this was obviously a wrong version and I guess the one for Xamarin not MAUI. I tried the version you posted above!

I used a  <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"   in a <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>. When I click a BottomTabItem. The corresponding "SelectedTabColor"-Property is set and applied with the Color I applied. But is there a possibility to change the form and also the color of the BottomTab itself? Currently, it choses the same Color for the "SelectedTabColor". I wanted to set a different one here

Comment: The author of that package provides a sample application in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) of the plugin where the different features are showcased.

Comment: I know, but there is no example for that. In a MAUI Section in the Tabs documentation there it is mentioned that a „Command.Tap“ and „TouchEffevct.Color“ is available. I tried to use it directly with „tabs:TouchEffect.Color=…“ I’m the TabItem within XAML, but wasn’t working. Would be nice to have an impact on the Shape of this TouchEffect with rounded borders and different Color

Comment: Is it somehow possible to change the Views in the Switcher from outside the MainPage where the Switcher is used? I have an Add-Button that should open up another view from within a View and Change it. Also on this View there is a OK-/Cancel-Button that should switch back from where I came